# Finding word correspondence with Microsoft Translator API

Tags: microsoft-translator

If you translate text on bing translate (www.bing.com/translator), you can see which word in the source text corresponds to a given word in the translated text. Just hover your mouse pointer over a word.

e.g. If you translate "Fantastic journey" into French, you get "Voyage fantastique" The first word in the source text corresponds to the second word in the translated text.

Is this operation possible via the Microsoft Translator API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can retrieve the word alignment from the Translator API. Details explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198370.aspx.

Comment: Chris, it looks like the word alignment hover-over no longer works on the bing translate website. Is it going away from the backend as well? Also can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148764/obtaining-alignment-data-for-english-to-chinese

Comment: That's right, it disappeared with the transition to neural networks. We are working on hard on bringing it back. You can still get it from the API if you force SMT translation using category=smt in the Translator API.

Comment: Is there a timeline on bringing it back?

Comment: For the API, the English-to-Chinese no longer gives word alignment (though the docs promise it), is it because the transition to neural networks already happened for that pair?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148764/obtaining-alignment-data-for-english-to-chinese/47164517#47164517