# Obtaining alignment data for English to Chinese

Tags: microsoft-translator

Using TranslateArray2, I am able to get alignment data for most languages I want, but not for English to Chinese (zh). How can I get it?

```
<ArrayOfTranslateArray2Response xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <TranslateArray2Response>
    <Alignment />
    <From>en</From>
    <OriginalTextSentenceLengths xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      <a:int>33</a:int>
    </OriginalTextSentenceLengths>
    <TranslatedText>你好我的朋友, 我爱你的唇</TranslatedText>
    <TranslatedTextSentenceLengths xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      <a:int>13</a:int>
    </TranslatedTextSentenceLengths>
  </TranslateArray2Response>
</ArrayOfTranslateArray2Response>
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198370.aspx

It claims that from English to any language there should be alignment data:

> Alignment is only returned for a subset of the language pairs at this
>   point: from English to any other language; from any other language to
>   English except for Chinese Simplified, Chinese Traditional, and
>   Latvian to English from Japanese to Korean or from Korean to Japanese

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The article indicates some language pairs as exceptions. It will work for Chinese (for the first time) when we bring it back to our neural network languages.

We are working on it and will announce it on the Microsoft Translator blog.

Comment: Can you provide timeline? Also see my original post - it seems that the article says that all English to X translations should have word alignment. If there is some older category I can use that would be appreciated.

Comment: ENU->CHS is NMT only and we do not support alignment data for NMT yet.

Comment: Curious if this is months away or much longer